# Are there recommended ways for drawing 2d array in fast time?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, metal, coreml, accelerate-framework

I want to draw a 2d array on iOS in fast time. The 2d array is like [heat map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_map), [depth map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_map) or [segmentation map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation), etc.

In my case, with `UIKit` framework, drawing big size array, like `500x500` shape, is too slow.

```swift
// my solution, but it's too slow
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
        let heatmap = self.heatmap else { return }

    ctx.clear(rect);

    let size = self.bounds.size
    let heatmap_w = heatmap.count
    let heatmap_h = heatmap.first?.count ?? 0
    let w = size.width / CGFloat(heatmap_w)
    let h = size.height / CGFloat(heatmap_h)

    for j in 0..<heatmap_w {
        for i in 0..<heatmap_h {
            let value = heatmap[i][j]
            let alpha: CGFloat = CGFloat(value)
            guard alpha > 0 else { continue; }
            
            let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * w, y: CGFloat(j) * h, width: w, height: h)
            
            let color: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: alpha*0.58)
            
            let bpath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
            
            color.set()
            bpath.stroke()
            bpath.fill()
        }
    }
    
} // end of draw(rect:)
```

I think `Metal` or `CoreGraphics` framework are related to this problem, but I couldn't find the proper example or material. Are there any recommended ways?

### heatmap example

[image: depthmap example]

updated:

[Here](https://github.com/tucan9389/SemanticSegmentation-CoreML/pull/7) is segmentation post-processing implementation example with MetalKit. The latency of post-processing was down to `1 ms` from `240 ms` on iPhone 11 Pro.

I referred [MetalCamera](https://github.com/jsharp83/MetalCamera) a lot.

[image: segmentation-demo]

new updated:

[Here](https://github.com/tucan9389/DepthPrediction-CoreML/pull/2) is depth prediction post-processing implementation example with MetalKit and Accelerate framework. The latency of post-processing was down to `1 ms` from `15 ms` on iPhone 11 Pro.

[image: depthmap-demo]

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use **Metal Compute Function** to achieve maximum performance.
Apple has a good [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/processing_a_texture_in_a_compute_function?language=objc) that shows the basics. Additionally you can use [Metal Performance Shaders](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders?language=objc) to implement custom rendering functions or to take advantage of a large library of existing functions.